# Passing command args to docker api

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-api

I'm attempting to find the equivalent of

```
docker run -it networkstatic/nflow-generator -t localhost -p 9995
```

when using the docker API (I'm using dockerode, but an answer for the HTTP api is just as good). I tried this with no luck:

```
docker.createContainer({
  Image: 'networkstatic/nflow-generator',
  Args: [ '-t', 'streamsets-dc', '-p', '9995' ]
});
```

How do I pass arguments without a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `networkstatic/nflow-generator` [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/networkstatic/nflow-generator/~/dockerfile/) already defines its entrypoint as `/go/bin/nflow-generator`, you should be able to pass these arguments into the running container as `command`s like this:

```
 docker.createContainer({
   Image: 'networkstatic/nflow-generator',
   Cmd: [ '-t', 'streamsets-dc', '-p', '9995' ]
 });
```